# Mi aplicacion ha dejado de funcionar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Buen día con todos, tengo un problema estoy desarrollando una apk en android studio y le estoy haciendo pruebas para ver si funciona correctamente y me percatado que en mi celular funciona  correctamente (lo he ejecutado la aplicación directamente de android studio atraves de cable usb)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero hay un detalle (estoy trabajando con functions de firebase para las notificaciones) ami no me llegan las notificaciones que se envían desde las funciones, pero si de la consola Cloud Messaging.

he generado la apk en otros dispositivos y las notificaciones que envió a través de la función si llegan, pero hay un problema al momento de entrar al apk en otros dispositivos la aplicación funciona pero cuando llego a entrar a un determinado activity se detiene.

dispositvo de prueba uno (intento entrar al carrito)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dispositivo de prueba dos (entra al carrito y muestra el detalle y se detiene en unos segundos).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el dispositivo 2 llegue presionar el boton de ordenar(el los segundos antes que se detenga la aplicación) y se genero el pedido 
y ahora la aplicación esta que se ejecuta sin problemas, pero hay un detalle ahora no llegan las notificaciones que se envía a través de la funciones de firebase. al parecer se puesto igual que el dispositivo en donde se ejecuto la apliacion desde el mismo android studio por cable usb(al dispositivo 1 y 2 se le instalo el apk que se genero) mientras que en dispositivo 1 no deja acceder a carrito de compras.

y no se cual sea el problema de esto, tambien he vuelto a revisar el codigo
y no le encuantro errores.
bueno me percate de esto pero no se si el error se origene por esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en estos casos creo que es útil incluir el contenido del logcat en la pregunta

Comment: Puede ser muy util que muestres el logcat como te recomienda @Alfabravo, luego puedes verificar o imprimir que estas recibiendo en el bundle de la notificación, puede que tengas valores nulos que estés utilizando y por otro lado, si revisas la documentación de Firebase hay maneras de enviar una notificación desde el server y como android lo recibe en foreground and background.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: 2019-06-14 16:31:39.755 15510-15540/com.example.wonvasusuarios E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2019-06-14 16:31:39.757 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
2019-06-14 16:31:40.721 15510-15678/com.example.wonvasusuarios E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not found.

Comment: 2019-06-14 16:32:42.477 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-06-14 16:32:42.477 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-06-14 16:32:42.567 15510-15510/com.example.wonvasusuarios E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length  eso me aparece en el logcat